# How to increase mapped drive letters from Windows defaults?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I'm running out of drive letters to map my network drives. Does anyone know of a registry edit or any other way to increase the number of drive letters from the windows defaults (windows default is A-Z)?

Comment: Technically, drives are not limited to A-Z; one can have `[:` or `@:`, it's just that most programs will not accept them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to increase the number of drive letters. But you can still use more than 26 partitions by mounting them as NTFS mount point folder. If you do that the drive will behave like a folder inside another drive.

> To assign a mount-point folder path to a drive by using the Windows
>   interface In Disk Manager, right-click the partition or volume where
>   you want to assign the mount-point folder path, and then click Change
>   Drive Letter and Paths.
>
> Do one of the following:
>
> To assign a mount-point folder path, click Add. Click Mount in the
>   following empty NTFS folder, type the path to an empty folder on an
>   NTFS volume, or click Browse to locate it.
>
> To remove the mount-point folder path, click it and then click Remove.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321.aspx).

**Update:**
[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/293922/what-if-the-hard-disk-is-partitioned-into-more-than-26-sections-in-windows) explains it better. Possible duplicate.

Comment: You beat me to it! If you are looking for some more inspiration, check this one out: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/use-mount-points-if-you-run-out-of-windows-drive-letters/383

Comment: If I was running a non-English version of windows would I still be limited to 26 drive letters?

Answer (score 1):

Mountvol allows you to use „alternative” drive letters. Unfortunately, most programs (including Explorer) will not see them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an old DOS command called `SUBST` to assign more drive letters. Try 0-9 as a starting point. One big caveat though:

> If the network resource is unavailable (ie the server is down) SUBST
>   will continually retry - unlike NET USE which will try to connect once
>   and fail - depending on your application this may be a good or a bad
>   thing - a subst drive that is not available will badly impact
>   performance of most applications.

Source: [SUBST](http://ss64.com/nt/subst.html)