# What happens when windows runs out of drive letters?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, windows-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What if the hard disk is partitioned into more than 26 sections in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/293922/what-if-the-hard-disk-is-partitioned-into-more-than-26-sections-in-windows)

What happens when windows runs out of drive letters?

I searched Google and got no definite answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Then it can not assign a new drive letter to a volume which has none.

Luckily drive letters are completely optional, and you can mount drives in folders.

(Take a look at disk-management, you can remove a drive letter from a volume; and if desired, mount it in a path).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Once you run out of drive letters Windows will force you to mount drives to a [NTFS folder](https://superuser.com/questions/293922/what-if-the-hard-disk-is-partitioned-into-more-than-26-sections-in-windows/293925#293925) or [mount points](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/use-mount-points-if-you-run-out-of-windows-drive-letters/383) rather than a drive letter.

Answer (score 2):

the end - of drive letters - 
you can still mount to a folder (mount point)

personally i think it's silly (ok, ridiculous) for Windows to maintain the drive letter scenario

Comment: Nope. Drive letters are user friendly. I would understand your reasoning with Windows supporting *only* drive letters, but as yourself said they also support mount points.