# I have 30 hard drives of which 12 are Linux. How do I give them drive letters? I also have about 3 usb that need drive letters as well

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, ntfs, usb-storage, ext3

I used to have 2 main workstations. Windows and Linux - Ubuntu for the Linux. Between the two of them, I had more than 30 hard drives in 2 NAS boxes operating on a JBOD basis and each workstation having about 6 and 8 internal drives.
Now I am consolidating all the drives on one workstation (with the exception of the internal drives of the second workstation)

I will now have a Windows workstation with 28 hard drives and 3 USB attached drives of which 12 are Linux  and ext3 file system (read using extfsd) and the rest windows.
Problem is if I start windows with all drives attached, half of the drives disappear and I don't know which NAS box is which - media files and extfsd is transparent.

The NTFS drives (> 20 including USB) have scripts and programs already attached which startup so I can't rework - my HPZ800 is temperamental. Can't risk it.

Why do I NOT want to use folders? I may spend the next year devising a folder scheme and where to mount it. Lets just say I have issues.

My question is how can I permanently address the Linux drives without using numbers and empty folders? Can I use Alphanumeric i.e. A1 for the first Linux and M1 for the last 12 (skipping I1 - easy to get wrong.

```
A1
B1
C1
And so on
```

This is not a duplicate of any question because I want to use a specific addressing system on a specific file management system.

Comment: 30 drives all spinning up at the same time will draw a lot of power. (30x roughly10 to 20W) I hope you have a good PSU or one with plenty spare capacity.

Comment: So instead of a folder scheme you're deciding on a letter scheme. If you're fine with A1, B1, etc., why not mount them on c:/mnt/A1, c:/mnt/B1, etc.?

Comment: @Hennes These z800 workstations have 800, 1000 and 1200 PSU's available. But you can't stuff 30 drives internally, (I never managed to shoe-horn more than 22 in one), so I presume he uses a NAS box that can be used as an external SATA enclosure. And which has it's own powersupply

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/293922/what-if-the-hard-disk-is-partitioned-into-more-than-26-sections-in-windows

Comment: @Hennes - they are 2 separate JBOD  each powered.

Comment: @grawity If I mount 26 drives on C drive, will all the  hdd size sum into C drive? If they will, is there any theoretical limit on how much one single drive can have? I am looking at about 80TB here. From windows viewpoint?

Comment: @Mokubai and I distinctly referenced that post. There:  is it possible? here how do i address them. I'd say different.

Comment: @seanbw: No. Each drive's capacity remains independent. The only difference is that you're accessing them under a different name.

Answer (score 2):

Linux doesn't have "drive letters". Instead you **mount** a filesystem somewhere in a directory tree. In other words, everything is a folder. No way around that. You can give your folders any name you want, so a single letter (or a letter with a number) is fine. If that makes you happy.

Now *Windows* does have a problem, because you can't assign more than the 26 letters of the alphabet, so you will have to do something else ...

As for accessing Linux drives from Windows remotely, you could also just export the single parent folder of all the mounted folders (however you choose the names), and assign a single letter to thet exported folder. There's no need to export whole filesystems only.

I'd also question whether it's a good idea to consolidate *all* drives into a single computer ...

Comment: Windows lets you mount drives on an arbitrary path, no problems. Only OP specifically does not _want_ to do that.

Comment: @grawity: Exactly. "something else" = use the path. Or the remote name.

Comment: Windows has 26 drive-letters, out of which A, B and C are already assigned, leaving at most 23. Poster says he has 20+ already assigned. But he only needs one letter for mounting, which can then be deleted and reused ([link](http://ask-leo.com/26_drives_is_there_a_way_around_the_26_drive_limit_in_windows.html)). (I also think that this complex architecture will be fragile.)

Comment: Looks as if I have to mount in a folder.  I guess the procedure is to create the folders first, plug JBOD in and then run disk management with ExtFSD. @grawity =use the path. Or the remote name. = Does this solution not result in a pool of the 26 drives? All 80TB of them. Will it become a poll of 20 sub folders?

Answer (score 0):

In the old days you could do double drive-letters if you had the Novell Netware client installed, but ONLY for network drives as far as I recall.
This may still be possible on modern Windows. I never had a reason to try it.

If it still works today you could mount the individual drives on folders and then share the mount-points. Map those shares via \\localhost\share with double drive-letters and you will simulate the effect.

Of course access to those drives will take a performance hit, because everything must go via the network stack. Even though the traffic won't actually leave the PC you still have the overhead of the network stack.